# Search nodes using dbid in alfresco?

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr4, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have some Database ID's. I have tried to run query to find out the corresponding nodes but it's not working. Tell me how to write a correct query using Database ID?

Comment: do you want to search nodes from the `Alfresco` database ?!?

Comment: I am using this query to get document `SELECT * FROM cm:document WHERE IN_TREE('" +
wikiFolder.getId() +
"')`

Comment: No not directly from database. i want to run a alfresco or solr query,i am using **sys;node-dbid:1190** but its not working

Comment: If my answer worked for you could you please accept it. If not please let us know what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

In Node Browser (Admin Tools) you can run following query selecting *lucene* as language from dropdown:

```
@sys\:node-dbid:1190
```

To search with *alfresco-fts* option you need to escape hyphen with `\`:

```
sys\:node\-dbid:1190
```